# Looking for clarification on use of USING in C#

Tags: c#, scope, using

I am debugging some old code in which the original developer does something like this:

```
public bool ProcessFooStuff()
{
    List<Foo> fooList;
    using (var dbContext = new FooEntities())
    {
        var id = 1;
        fooList= _fooRepository.GetFoo(dbContext, id);
    }
    ProcessFooList(fooList);
}

public List<Foo> GetFoo(FooEntitiesdbContext, int id)
{
    List<Foo> fooList;
    try
    {
        fooList = dbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.id == id).ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return fooList;
}

public bool ProcessFooList(List<Foo> fooList)
{
    using (var dbContext = new FooEntities())
    {
        .
        . 
        .
        fooList.RemoveAll(f => f.Id = x);
        .
        .
        .
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    
}
```

There is an intermittent issue with items from the Foo table getting deleted unexpectedly. I speculate that it is because the IDispose on the first USING block is not cleaning up its instance of fooList because it is scoped outside the block and the SaveChanges in the method fooList is being passed to is acting on it.

Can anyone confirm or debunk?

Thanks.

Comment: removeall deletes, why is that unexpected? What code do you have in the .... lines?

Comment: What is the actual type of the object returned from `GetFoo`? Not the one being declared, the one actually being returned? Is it an actual `List<Foo>` or is it a list object that inherits from `List<T>` and is somehow tied to the database context or whatnot? If it is just a `List<T>`, then it will not delete anything from the underlying table.

Comment: I'm not following. You say *not cleaning up its instance of Foo*. I don't see any Foo instances in your code, only a `List<Foo>`. Lists don't implement `Disposable` so it doesn't matter. Then you pass that (in memory only) list to `ProcessFoo` which deletes some or all of the items from the in memory list while doing some database work. But, this had nothing to do with the database. Sorry, otherwise I'm not following what you are saying/asking

Comment: The code in the ... after the RemoveAll is adding records to the Foo table after excluding fooList.
All parameters are being passed as List<Foo>
What I am hoping to clarify is whether or not since the original List<Foo> fooList is declared outside the Using block, it is somehow still attached to the db after begin passed into ProcessFooList and the SaveChanges in ProcessFooList is deleting stuff i t is not intended to delete.

I am seriously grabbing at straws here as I'm running out of options except the guy that swears he is never deleting things from the table.

Comment: Do you want us to comment on the code you *don't* show? Unless a class implements Disposable, it doesn't care about `using`. Your Foo list is declared at function scope in ProcessFooStuff and GetFoo. So, you can return them. Then it gets passed as a parameter to ProcessFooList, so it's not eligible for collection. What do you see when you debug this?

Comment: This is going sideways quickly.  All I am looking for is assurance that the RemoveAll is not impacting records in the database. I have been chasing this for two days and am too deep to see clearly.  Thanks for all your feedback and especially your patience with my inability to explain my question properly

Comment: Your call to RemoveAll has a single = (assignment) rather than a double == (comparison), not sure whether that is significant

Comment: Let me try this:  fooList is defined outside the scope of the Using block that instantiates a dbContext which means when the Using block ends, the context is disposed, fooList is not.  FooList is then passed to another function that instantiates another dbContext inside another Using block inside of which, the Removal is used to filter fooList.  Is there still any chance of the binding between fooList and the underlying db table existing and will RemoveAll impact the database table?  I am thinking no but the only other answer is human error which is being vehemently denied.

Answer (score 0):

Using only cleans up the item inside the using statement.  dbContext will get Disposed called in both functions.

This code looks like it was designed to delete foos, it uses two separate database contexts to do so, but it gets the list of foos, deletes them, and then saves it's changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The dispose method will always dispose the dbcontext once done.
Using is just sintactic sugar for try finally block that runs dispose for the idisposable object in the using stayment.

Please try and post your process method code, the issue is somewhere there probably

Good luck